# Build JSON Hierarchy from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

C# | .NET 4.5 | Entity Framework 5

I have data coming back from a SQL Query in the form of ID,RoleName,ParentId. I'd like to take that data and parse it into a Hierarchical JSON string. So far it seems to be much more of a daunting task than it should be. Since I'm using Entity the data comes back nicely to me as an IEnumerable. Now I believe I just need some form of recursion, but I'm not quite sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

**Data Returns as**

```
    id   parentId    name
1   1      Null       ED
2   2      1          CPD
3   3      2          Centre Manager 
4   4      3          Manager
5   5      4          Sales Head
6   6      4          Technical Head
7   7      5          Sales Individual
8   8      6          Technical Individual
```

**Code Is**

```
public ActionResult getJsonTree()
{
    var roles = getChilds(null).ToArray();
    return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private IEnumerable<RoleVM> getChilds(int? parentID)
{
    return _db.Roles
        .Where(r => r.ParentID == parentID)
        .Select(x =>
                new RoleVM()
                {
                    text=x.RoleName,
                    icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
                    node=getChilds(x.Id)
                }).ToList();
}
```

**Model Class is**

```
public partial class Role
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string RoleName { get; set; }
  public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
}

public class RoleVM
{
  public string text { get; set; }
  public string icon { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RoleVM> node { get; set; }
}
```

**The end result I'd hope would be something like this:**

```
var tree = [{
  text: "ED",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
  nodes: [{
    text: "CPD",
    icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    nodes: [{
      text: "Center Manager",
      icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
      nodes: [{
        text: "Manager",
        icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
        nodes: [{
          text: "Tech Head",
          icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
          nodes: [{
            text: "Individual",
            icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
          }]
        }]

      }]

    }]
  }]
}];
```

**What I am getting is as follows**

```
[

  {

    "text": "ED",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "CPD",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Centre Manager",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Manager",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  }, {

    "text": "Tech Head",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null

  },

  {
    "text": "Individual",
    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "node": null
  }

]
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of both **RoleVM** and **Role**?
One way to achieve that is to use recursion.